# Set List of Class Property value to NULL without Foreach

Tags: c#

Might be simple but am not sure how to implement without foreach

```
public class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

Am having  List with 1000 Count

Now i need to set LastModified to Null for all the 1000 Records.

```
foreach(var item in Car)
{
item.LastModified = null;
}
```

Without Foreach is there any other better way i can implement ?

Thanks

Comment: what is wrong with this ?

Comment: @Selman22 just to know(Leran) if there any other ways i can do this. I cant get a better placer than SO for this :)

Comment: A `foreach` is about as simple/"best" as they come for this task. If you're doing this often, you can create a static method (or extension method) to do this for you and avoid duplicating the loop throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

As Christos says Linq is one way to achieve this goal, however [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7851940/1775471) by Jon Skeet to a similar question explains why you shouldn't use it.

You're not querying here so use the standard foreach loop, possibly with an [extension method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension) as Chris Sinclair mentions.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `ForEach` method (not a keyword) you can use:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
cars.ForEach((c) => c.LastModified = null);
```